# How to get a variable from a object in an object (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

I'm making a basic game using storyboard. I have multiple views(of course) and when re-opening views, they reset. So, I created a class that appdelaget should make an object off.
Now, I import appdelaget to all the views that need to pass variables/not to reset when view is reloaded. Now,
does anyone know how i get a variable from an object that's created inside another object. Anyway, it's hard to explain, here are the classes that matter:

VariableControll.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface VariableControl : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int maxNr;
@property (nonatomic) int nrSet;
@property (nonatomic) int guessNr;
```

VariableControll.m:

```
#import "VariableControl.h"

@implementation VariableControl

@synthesize maxNr;
@synthesize guessNr;
@synthesize nrSet;

@end
```

This is a simple class that will save the variables that will pass through views.

Appdelaget.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VariableControl.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Appdelaget.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:                  
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    VariableControl *VarControll = [[VariableControl alloc] init];

    VarControll.maxNr = 100;

    VarControll.nrSet = arc4random() %VarControll.maxNr;

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
//More methods are not listed becouse they're non-touched//
```

Game.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface Game : UIViewController

//User interaction and labels
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *theTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *theInput;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *theMessage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *theTabTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *theGuessButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *theNewGameButton;

//Variables
@property (nonatomic) int number;
@property (nonatomic) int guess;
@property (nonatomic) int nrOfGuess;
@property (nonatomic) int maxNr;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *guessString;

//Actions
- (IBAction)guess:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)newGame:(id)sender;

@end
//Have some non-neded outlets becouse I tried to fix SIGABRT error, and didn't remove 
them(btw, I have solved sigabrt!!!!)//
```

Game.m:

```
#import "Game.h"

@implementation Game

@synthesize theTitle;
@synthesize theInput;
@synthesize theMessage;
@synthesize theTabTitle;
@synthesize theGuessButton;
@synthesize theNewGameButton;
@synthesize number;
@synthesize nrOfGuess;
@synthesize guess;
@synthesize guessString;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    AppDelegate *StartUp = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];

    return YES;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //When the user taps somwhere away from the keyboard, it disapears
    [theInput resignFirstResponder];

    [theTabTitle setTitle:@"Game"];

    [theNewGameButton setTitle:@"New Game" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [theGuessButton setTitle:@"Guess" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //set a random number and clear variables

    nrOfGuess = 0;
    guess = 0;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTheTitle:nil];
    [self setTheInput:nil];
    [self setTheMessage:nil];
    [self setTheTabTitle:nil];
    [self setTheGuessButton:nil];
    [self setTheNewGameButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [theInput resignFirstResponder];
    //If the user touches outside the keyboard, it will disapear
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)guess:(id)sender {

    guess = [[theInput text] intValue];

    if (guess == number) {

    guessString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Corret! You guessed %i times!",  nrOfGuess];

    [theMessage setText: guessString];

    number = arc4random() %101;
    nrOfGuess = 0;
    guess = 0;

}

else {

    if (guess < number) {

        [theMessage setText:@"Sorry! Guessed too low!"];

        nrOfGuess = nrOfGuess + 1;

        [theInput setText:@""];
    }
    else    {

        [theMessage setText:@"Sorry! Guessed too high!"];

        nrOfGuess = nrOfGuess + 1;

        [theInput setText:@""];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)newGame:(id)sender {
    //set a random number and clear variables
    number = arc4random() %101;

    nrOfGuess = 0;
    guess = 0;
}
@end
```

Now, the question is; in game.m, how can I get the variable maxNr in "VarControll" That's an object of class VariableControll created in appdelaget.m. I can't possibly do

```
number = StartUp.VarControll.maxNr;
```

it will just give me an error!

BTW, don't get mad at me if this is the stupidest question you'we ever seen, or has the most obvious answer, I'm a beginner to objective c.

Thanx in advice, JomanJi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically easy to solve, if I understand your question right that is..

So you defined some variables that should be handed over to the next view?

Since you say you are using storyboard, you can hand these values over via your segue command.

Quick example...

In viewOne, you create a variable called MaxNr. (no need to declare them in  seperate class!!)

So when you go to viewTwo, you use the following segue lines:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"gotoViewTwo"])
{
UIViewController *viewTwo = [segue destinationViewController];
viewTwo.maxNr=self.maxNr;
}
```

This will hand over the value of MaxNr to viewTwo.

In viewTwo you obviously have to declare and synthesize your maxNr.

```
viewTwo.h
....

@property (nonatomic) (int) maxNr;

viewTwo.m
....

@synthesize maxNr;
```

If you want to check whether you did it right, you put in viewTwo didLoad following line:

```
NSLog(@"My viewTwo maxNr value is %u",maxNr);
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: lol, I thought I did..... sorry!

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be missing is an understanding of what an `instance variable` or a `property` is, and this is fundamental to understanding object-oriented programming in Objective-C.

Consider your "Appdelaget.h" where the property `window` is defined. This property belongs to instances of `AppDelegate`. So you can write:

```
AppDelegate *StartUp = [[AppDelegate alloc] init]; // create your instance of AppDelegate
NSWindow *theWindow = Startup.window; // obtain the value of the window property
```

However your variable `VarControll` is not an instance variable (i.e. belong to) your class, but is a *local variable* (i.e. belongs to) a method - it comes into existence when the method is called and is destroyed when the method exists. That is why you cannot write:

```
Startup.VarControll; // wrong, Startup has no property VarControll
Startup->VarControll; // also wrong, Startup has no instance variable VarControll
```

One solution to your problem is to add an instance variable (or property) of type `VariableControl` to your `AppDelegate` class and set that up in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method instead of using a local variable. But that may not be the right answer for your problem. You might want to read up on local vs. instance variables, and the lifetimes of variables and objects to help your understanding.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that what I did wrong was that I used local variables and not instance variables